# How to get the inner offset of a ClickEvent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, onclick, dom-events, mouseevent

I want to get the "inner offset", or rather the inner coordinates of a clicked element via the Javascript Click-Event. As you can see in the image, I need the Offset X and Offset Y. Is there any property which gives me this information?

Using plain Javascript and the "mousedown" and "mousemove" event.

[image]

Comment: Does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties of the `MouseEvent` object.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the values you want are offsetX and offsetY values

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const element = document.getElementById("child");
  const offsetX = (e.clientX - element.offsetLeft)
  const offsetY = (e.clientY - element.offsetTop)
}
```